# Qtableview in qvboxlayout

Tags: pyqt4, qtableview, qvboxlayout

Hello I'm trying to embbed a qtableview in a qvbox layout
But I do not manage to keep the qtableview in the qvboxlayout
The code below gives me two windows I do not know why layout.addwidget does not behave as expected.

```
class QMT(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(QMT, self).__init__(parent)
        layout=QVBoxLayout(self)        
        self.view = QtGui.QTableView()
        self.name = QtGui.QLabel("Name:")      
        layout.addWidget(self.view)
        layout.addWidget(self.name)
        self.initUI() #Windows stuff + show()
        self.setLayout(layout)
```

Comment: What's `self.initUI` ? Do you use QtDesigner and ui files ?

Comment: self.initUI() is menu (open, close stuff). I have found the answer I will post here. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

I answer myself and found basic statement I did not understand about PyQt:

**There are 2 steps to using the layout system in Qt: organizing widgets into a layout, and applying a layout to a widget.**

So here is something that work :

```
class QMT(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(QMT, self).__init__(parent)

        # Create Qtable view widget
        self.view = QtGui.QTableView(self)

        # Create Canvas for graph
        self.fig=Figure(figsize=(5,5), dpi=100)
        self.canvas=FigureCanvas(self.fig)
        self.graph=self.fig.add_subplot(111)

        #Layout management
        #Initiate splitter (more convenient for end user)
        splitter1 = QtGui.QSplitter(QtCore.Qt.Horizontal)
        splitter1.addWidget(self.view)
        splitter1.addWidget(self.canvas)

        # Create Horizontal Layout Box
        hbox = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
        # Add the splitter to the hbox 
        hbox.addWidget(splitter1)

        #initiate widget to be shown
        widget = QtGui.QWidget(self)
        widget.setLayout(hbox)

        #Set widget as central widget
        self.setCentralWidget(widget)

        # Windows & Menu stuff
        self.initUI()
```